# Succinct initialization of nested templated pointer types

Tags: c++

Given the following type:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
  A(const T& t) : t_(t) {}
  T t_;
};
```

If I have a variable of type `A<A<A<int>>>`, I could initialize it as

```
A<A<A<int>>> a = A<A<A<int>>>(A<A<int>>(A<int>(1)));
```

or less verbosely as

```
A<A<A<int>>> a = {{{1}}};
```

Now suppose I have a variable of type `A<A<A<int*>*>*>*`.  I could initialize it as:

```
A<A<A<int*>*>*>* a = new A<A<A<int*>*>*>(new A<A<int*>*>(new A<int*>(new int(1)));
```

But to be less verbose... I'm stuck.  There's no `new` version of a braced init list, and attempting to use template argument deduction to save repeating types gets stuck on being unable to infer return types.  (ie. I couldn't get `a = make_a(make_a(make_a(1)))` to work.)

Is there a way to not inflict eye pain upon readers of my code?

Comment: Working with a pointer to an object of type `A<A<A<int*>*>*>` raises red flags. Have you thought about a strategy for managing the dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: Also, the posted code is syntactically incorrect. You'll have to use `A<A<A<int*>*>*>* a = new A<A<A<int*>*>*>(new A<A<int*>*>(new A<int*>(new int(1))));`

Comment: This seemed like the simplest meaningful example, with the actual case perhaps more resembling an std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<...>>, so memory management isn't of as much concern, and the concrete case involves a variety of composed types.  The overall idea is still "what do I do when brace init lists fail because pointers?"  And I've edited the code to be correct, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a `typedef`/`using`?

Comment: It is not clear to me how that would resolve the issue.  If you can avoid writing `A<` O(^2) times with a `typedef` or `using`, I'd be happy to see such an answer.

Comment: I am really interested to know what actual use case you might have for this, because besides being a thought example, I can't come up with one, but I would truly love to hear what your use case is. :)